# How to re render a react class component with new data on route change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I would like to know what the best way would be to reuse a React class component.

I want to re render the same component on navigation so that the same component would appear but with all new data. I basically have some questions that the user needs to answer but would like them to appear on multiple pages rather than all on just one page. The user would then answer some questions and be able to go back and forth to review their answers. I am using Redux to store the data.

```
<Route path="/" exact render={(props) => <Home />} />
<Route to='/Questions' exact render={(props) => <Questions {...props} complete={this.finished} />} />




class Questions extends React.Component {
renderQuestions() {
    return this.props.dataAss.map((quest) => {
        if (quest) {
            return this.props.questions.map((q, questIdx) => {
                return (
                    <div key={q.id}>
                        <div className={this.state.question}>
                            <div id={q.id}>
                                <h3 className={this.state.title}>{q.title}</h3>
                                <SanitizedHTML html={`<p>${q.questionText}<p>`} />
                                <div key={q.id}>
                                    {q.options.map((opt, optIdx) => (
                                        <div key={opt.id} >
                                            <button key={opt.id}
                                                ref={this.options}
                                                className={`                                                            
                                                ${this.props.dataPersisted.singleSelection.includes(q.id + opt.id) && !q.multi ? "selected" : ""}                                                               
                                                ${this.props.dataPersisted.selection.includes(q.id + opt.id) ? "selected disabled" : ""}                                    
                                                ${this.props.dataPersisted.optState.includes(q.id + opt.id) && q.multi ? "selected" : ""}                                                                                           
                                                ${this.props.dataPersisted.questionState.includes(q.id) ? "disabled" : ""}                                                                                      
                                                ${this.state.options} ${this.props.dataPersisted.disabled} ${opt.val}
                                                `}
                                                disabled={this.props.dataPersisted.disabled} id={opt.id} onClick={(e) => {
                                                    q.multi ? this.multiToggle(e, q, opt) : this.singleToggle(e, q, opt);
                                                    e.stopPropagation();
                                                    this.InitialbuttonStates(questIdx);
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <span>{opt.label}</span>
                                                {opt.text}
                                            </button>

                                        </div>
                                    ))}
                                </div>
                                <button
                                    className={`${this.state.submit}`}
                                    disabled={`${(questIdx === this.state.checkAns) ? "" : "disabled"}`}
                                    onClick={(e) => { this.checkAnswer(e, q) }}
                                >
                                    Check Answer
                              </button>
                                <PopUp
                                    correct={this.state.correct}
                                />
                            </div>

                        </div >
                        <div className={this.state.image}>
                            <img src={q.img} alt={q.alt}></img>
                        </div>
                    </div >
                );
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is guarantee that I can uniquely identify an assessment (for example, by using `ids`).

After that, I would create an `Assessment` component that would load the questions based on an `id` on mount. This component would render the `Questions` component.

Finally, I'd provide such id with a [URL Parameter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params).

PS: A suggestion: I would have a `Question` component to render a single question and render multiple `Question` within the `Assessment` component using an [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: The problem I am having is how to re render the same question component with the new questions and then be able to go back and view the previous questions